# FormView unable to populate with existing user data

Tags: django, django-forms

I am attempting to create a custom `UserChangeForm` with Django 1.6, but the form is not being populated with existing data.

form:

```
class MyPatientEditForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['password']
```

view:

```
class PatientUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = MyPatientEditForm        
    template_name = "patient/patient_edit.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('patient_list')
```

urls:

```
url(r'^patient/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)$', PatientUpdate.as_view(), name="patient_edit"),
```

Am i missing a link to the PK somewhere or what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormView` doesn't update objects, it just handles form processing. The generic view you are looking for is `UpdateView`:

```
class PatientUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    # ...
```

Comment: I have been down that road, unfortunately for `UpdateView` i need to define a entire model, which is not what i wish, since i only want the user to modify a few variables hence i would like to get `Forms` into play. Is that possible without actually creating a custom user?

Comment: The `UpdateView` is a subclass of `ProcessFormView`, so setting a `form_class` should work

Comment: Another thing. In my particular usecase i am excluding `password` but i get an exception when submitting the form `KeyError: u'password'`. Does this have anything to do with the field being missing upon post?

Comment: I guess so, have a look at the traceback to see where the error occurs

Comment: The traceback is found here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e4f0032724b30fa8c4e0

Comment: Ah, your form extends `UserChangeForm` which expects the `password` field to be there. You might need to re-implement the form

Comment: Auch. Is there any chance that that i can save the fields behind the scenes? And by reimplementing, do you mean the entire `UserChangeForm`?

Comment: Well, it's not too bad. A large chunk of the `UserChangeForm` is actually dealing with the password and permissions anyways, [have a look at the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L127)